# How to return back to the parent activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 activity calling 1 activity eg

```
  Activity 1
      Activity a
  Activity 2
      Activity a
```

I want to return back from Activity a to which ever activity it was called from.

Currently I am getting null pointer exception saying Activity a has no parent activity defined.

Activity 1 and 2 as below

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

//         TextView urlTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.url);     
//         String url = urlTv.getText().toString();
           String url = projectsList.get(position).get("url");             
           //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LaunchReadMoreActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("url", url);
           //intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
           startActivity(intent);

          }

        });
```

Activity A :
public class LaunchReadMoreActivity extends Activity{

```
WebView myWebView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.read_screen);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");  

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    //webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    myWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    try {
        // load the url
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//  //myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
//  myWebView.setInitialScale(50);
//  //myWebView.loadUrl(url);
//  myWebView.loadUrl(url);
//      

    setupActionBar();

}

    setupActionBar();
```

Comment: post all code i.e Activity 1 and Activity 2

Comment: Share your code for calling Activity. It might be possible that you are finishing calling Activity before called Activity lunched.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch Activity a, don't call finish() method inside Activity A and Activity B

Answer (score 1):

Call the Activity_a from Activity_1 and Activity_2 by the following code,

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_a.class);
startActivity(intent);
// make sure that don't finish the current activity, ie don't use  finish() method in Activity 1 or 2;
then in Activity_a override the method,

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        getIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        Activity_a.this.finish();
    }
```

hop this code will help you to solve the issue.

Comment: Tried this and nothing happens same crash or null pointer exception as I am using up from the actionbar